# Prononciation : ai vs ê

Tags: prononciation, diacritiques

J'ai participé aux événements :

> Faites de la Science et Fêtes de la Science.

Lors d'un discours (et sans donner des détails : le premier est un concours tandis que le second est une manifestation scientifique) il n'y a pas de façon de distinguer entre les deux, la prononciation étant la même, non ?

Comment: Ben non, on ne peut pas les distinguer à l'oreille.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Oui**, `faites` se prononce exactement comme `fêtes`  : `\fɛt\`.

Cela vaut pour toutes les variantes dialectales que je connais. Malheureusement, difficile de trouver des références solides quant à la prononciation de `ai` en français :)

Comment: Au Québec, ces mots sont prononcé distinctement. Je crois que la voyelle "pure" serait peut-être /ɜ:/, mais je ne suis pas super calé en phonétique, et de plus, c'est probablement la voyelle longue qui est le plus souvent diphtonguée en français québécois.

Answer (score 2):

Comme l'a dit Circeus, les dialectes de français Canadiens font une distinction entre les deux.

J'élabore: au Canada, les francophones prolongent le "ê" et le prononcent similairement au "ai" dans "Faille". La prononciation se rapproche du mont anglais *"fight"* (bataille).

Mais je ne connais aucun autre dialecte qui fait cette distinction.

vidéo de la prononciation **(attention: contient language vulgaire)** [ici](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-tffffWN4K0).

Comment: Je vous remercie de votre réponse !

Comment: Précision, "attention: contient language vulgaire": pour une oreille québecoise uniquement ;)